# Get image attribute based on class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some images which have `data-url` attribute i want to get the value of the `data-url` based on the click on an element.

### My html is

```
<img class="youtube-poster" src=" http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/juIJGBxj-4w/maxresdefault.jpg " data-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w">
<div class="video-poster-player"><i class="play"></i><div>
```

### And my js is

```
$(document).on('click', '.video-poster-player', function(event) {
  var className = $(event.target).attr('class');
  var frameurl = className.parent().find('.youtube-poster').data('url')

  console.log(className)
  console.log(frameurl)
});
```

In console it is `className.parent is not a function`

Comment: `img` isnt a parent element try `.closest('img')`

Comment: Instead of all that stuff, isn't it easier to just: `var frameurl = $('.video-poster-player').closest('img').data('url');` ?

Comment: className is a string, you can't do "parent()" on it, you need to target the element.

Answer (score 1):

So, `.parent()` is valid only on a jQuery object and not on a string (`className`). The following would work for your scenario (Not so pretty, but [works](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/wf72kxq2/)).

```
<img class="youtube-poster" src=" http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/juIJGBxj-4w/maxresdefault.jpg " data-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w">
<div class="video-poster-player">
    <i class="play">Play</i>
<div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.video-poster-player', function(event) {
    alert ($(this).prev('.youtube-poster').data('url'));
});
```

A cleaner solution would be to group your image and play icons, then use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get what you want, like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/wf72kxq2/1/).

Answer (score 1):

check working example. Let me know if u need further information.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.video-poster-player', function (event) {
    
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(className);
    var frameurl = $(this).parent().find('.youtube-poster').data('url');

    alert(className);
    alert(frameurl);
});
```

```css
.video-poster-player {
    
        background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img height="100px" class="youtube-poster" src=" http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/juIJGBxj-4w/maxresdefault.jpg " data-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w">
<div height="200px;"  style="color:red" class="video-poster-player"><i class="play"></i>

    <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to put a wrapping div around each block?  This way you can target things within the block:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="youtube-poster" src=" http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/juIJGBxj-4w/maxresdefault.jpg " data-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w">
    <div class="video-poster-player"><i class="play"></i></div>
</div>
```

I created a div that wraps the HTML.  That way you can reference it in JS as the parent.

```
$('.video-poster-player').click(function(){
    var img = $(this).parent().find('.youtube-poster');
    var data_url = $(img).attr('data-url');
    console.log(data_url);
});
```

The JS binds the click function to `.video-poster-player`.  When it is clicked, it looks up at the parent, and then back down for `.youtube-poster`.  Then it looks for the attribute `data-url` on that element.

[View Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVmMLV)